# Take input in array of bool

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

I want to take input in array of bool

```
bool bmp[32];
```

And this will be the program interaction.

```
 Enter binary number : 10101
```

I want to store user input of '10101' in array of bool like.

```
bmp[32]={1,0,1,0,1};
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing fancy, just read data and store it to array like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter binary number : ";
    std::cin >> str;
    bool b[32];
    std::size_t size = 0;
    for (auto c : str) {
        b[size++] = c == '1';
    }

    // you are all set now.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since this is C++, let's use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
std::cout << "Enter binary number : ";

std::bitset<32> b;
std::cin >> b;
```

It's not a `bool` array like you requested - but it's way better.

Comment: ...or a way worse=) In my personal opinion I would use a single `int` as a binary mask for this case.

Comment: @Anton And if you want 132 bits instead of 32?

Comment: then it is another story to tell. I simply mean that the solution strongly depends on the task and std::bitset is not always the right choice when you need some work to be done over the bloody bits.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but try something out on your own next time (and post the code you tried).

```
bool b[ 32 ];
std::string str = "10101";
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0U; i < str.length(); ++i )
    b[ i ] = str[ i ] == '1';
```

Or maybe

```
std::vector< bool > b;
std::string str = "10101";
b.reserve( str.length() );
for ( const char c : str )
    b.push_back( c );
```